# Combine output of two queries

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

SalesOrder - having 2 records

```
OrderID   Order Desc
101       My Order1
102       My Order2
```

SalesOrderLine - having the following records:

```
OrderID    Order_Line
101        10
101        20
102        10
102        20
102        30
```

My expected result is that when I execute a query, it should give me :

- TotalSalesordercount as 2; and
- `LineCount` as `2 for Order 101` and `3 for Order 102`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  t1.orderid, 
  count(distinct t1.orderid) as 'TotalSalesordercount', 
  count(*) as 'LineCount'   
from 
  SalesOrder T1, 
  SalesOrderLine T2
where 
  t1.orderid = t2.orderid
group by 
  t1.orderid
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to `JOIN` the two tables on the `OrderId` and then use an aggregate function:

```
select so.orderid,
  so.order_desc,
  count(ol.orderid) LineCount,
  (select count(*) from salesorder) TotalOrders
from salesorder so
inner join orderline ol
  on so.orderid = ol.orderid
group by so.orderid, so.order_desc;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5c91/6)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for your data:

```
select so.OrderId
  , TotalSalesordercount = (select count(distinct OrderId) from SalesOrderLine)
  , LineCount = count(1)
from SalesOrder so
  inner join SalesOrderLine sol on so.OrderId = sol.OrderId
group by so.OrderId
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5579/8).